# How to execute a test suite (Selenium Python) via Azure DevOps pipeline CI/CD?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I made a UI Test suite with Selenium Python and I want to deploy it to the linux VM and execute it via CI/CD pipeline.
This is my code:

```
deployment: VMDeploy
    displayName: UI Test Suite
    environment: 
      name: lastenv
      resourceType: VirtualMachine
      tags: web
    strategy:
       runOnce:
        deploy:
         steps:
         - task: Bash@3
           inputs:
            targetType: inline 
            script: |
                 #!/bin/bash
                 sudo apt-get upgrade -y
                 sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y
                 sudo apt-get install unzip -y
                 sudo apt-get install -y chromium-browser
                 pip3 install selenium
                 export PATH=$PATH:'selenium/testSuite.py'
```

Deploying of the VM was successfully completed and I can check that all the packages (**python3-pip**, **unzip**, **chromium-browser** and **selenium**) were installed in the VM.
The problem is I how to deploy the test suite **testSuite.py** and run it?!! - like I did it locally: `py testSuite.py`
I am wondering if `export PATH=$PATH:'selenium/testSuite.py'` is correct?
I simply don't understand how to deploy `testSuite.py` in VM-Linux using DevOps pipelines?

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: `py` is a Window thing. Use `python` or `python3` on Linux systems. But don't expect even that to work. You are going to need a graphical environment or a virtual frame buffer to run graphical UI tests.

Comment: Hi@Klaus D. you're right about `py`, it was a mistake. `py` is in Windows (made my test in Windows..forget to change it to `python`). I my **testSuite.py** I had included `print()`commands, so the actions of the tests can be determined. I tested it in a cmd-windows and it worked fine (no need for graphical env.). My problem is how to test it via CI/CD pipeline?

Comment: That was my point: pipelines usually do not run in a Window, they run on the pure (text) shell without graphics.

Comment: @carl What's the meaning of "deploy testSuite.py in VM-Linux"? Do you get any error when you run `python testSuite.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you don't know how to get the `testSuite.py` to the VM-Linux, then you should checkout the source repo (assuming the `testSuite.py` in your source repo) before running the command line.

A deployment job doesn't automatically clone the source repo. You can checkout the source repo within your job with `checkout: self`.

```
runOnce:
  deploy:
    steps:
    - checkout: self 
    - task: Bash@3
```

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful? Is your issue solved?